# variable not getting selected from text box value entered

Tags: javascript

```
function mineFunction(){ 
    var targetNumber = getElementById("userInput").value; 
    var startNumber = 0; 
    while (startNumber The number is " + i; startNumber++; 
    } 
    document.getElementById("displayHere").innerHTML = targetNumber; 
}
```

Trying to get the value from input box and display results through while loop. Code has some issue and not working. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs? Or just one? Why do you use a loop? Also, that's not how you use a `while` loop. Your code is full of syntax mistakes.

Comment: Sample While : while (i < 10) {
    text += "The number is " + i;
    i++;
}  you question has syntax errors.

Comment: Is there a copy-paste error in your `while` loop? Note that while the loop is running, the user won't be able to change the form input, because Javascript is single-threaded.